# How do I instantiate an object in PHP but only via another object

Tags: php, oop

Using the PHP Stripe Library (https://github.com/stripe) you can instantiate an object like so:

```
$stripe = new \Stripe\StripeClient( 'sk_test_secretkeyhere' );
$product = $stripe->products->retrieve( 'prod_abc123' );
```

I'm not looking to understand specifically how *Stripe* does it. But rather, how a simple example of this could be coded. In other words, how to ensure that a Products object can be instantiated with `$prod = $someobject->products->retrieve()` but prevent it being instantiated with `$prod = new Products`.

Also, making this happen without instantiating a Products object until the retrieve() method is called. So for example without instantiating a new Products object in the constructor of the Thing class - see below.

I got as far as this:

```
class Thing {

    function __get($name) {
      if ($name === 'products') {
        $p = new Products();
        return $p;
      }
    }

  }
  
class Products {

    public $id;
    public $option;

    function retrieve($id, $option) {
        $this->id = $id;
        $this->option = $option;
        return $this;
    }

}
```

With this code I can get a Products object using this:

```
$thing = new Thing();
$prod = $thing->products->retrieve('123', 'bob');
```

But in this case we can also instantiate a Products object like so:

```
$prod = new Products;
```

I'd like to prevent instantiating a Products object directly, and force it to happen via the $thing->products->retrieve() notation.

I feel like I must be missing something obvious.

TO CLARIFY: In Stripe's code, if you try to instantiate a Products object directly, it says there is no such class. You have to do it via the StripeClient object. It is this restriction that I am trying to emulate.

Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: Well what happens if you try to instantiate the Stripe "Products" class directly? Do you get an error? The error message, if any, might give a clue as to the implementation method perhaps.

Comment: One possible approach might be as described here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/9192322/5947043

Comment: No I don't get an error. That's the point. It doesn't error - it works. I don't want it to. I'd like it to error if using $prod = new Products. But I'd like $prod=$thing->products->retrieve() to continue working.

Comment: I see. The wording of your question implies that Stripe had succeeded in preventing you from instantiating their class directly. And you were asking how to imitate the same behaviour in your own code.

Comment: Sorry, I misunderstood you. I thought you were referring to my attempt. But now I see what you're getting at - and that's a good point I need to check it. I recalled previously trying it some time ago, but maybe my memory is not so good these days. I will check that point and confirm the result. Thanks.

Comment: Your `__get()` method is basically how it's done. But when you create the `Products` object you have to pass `$this` as a parameter so it knows which account's products to fetch from the API.

Comment: @ADyson if I try $prod = new \Stripe\Products it says no such class.

Comment: @Barmar If I understand you correctly, I don't think this solves the problem. Your suggestion would not prevent me instantiating an object with new Products.

Comment: I don't think you can. If you make the constructor private, it can't be called from `StripeClient` either.

Comment: I suspect this is done using different namespaces.

Comment: @Barmar Yes I also tried that. What I'm asking for is an example of some code that would achieve my goal, or at least point me in the right direction. For example, could it be achieved in some other way - maybe creating a Products class is not the right approach.

Comment: You also tried what? Multiple namespaces?

Comment: The Stripe API is open source, you should be able to read their code to see how they do it (although I'll admit that it's somewhat complex organization).

Comment: @Barmar No I also tried making the constructor private. I was typing that as you were adding the comment about namespaces so our messages crossed. Anyway, I don't think namespaces would help either because if the Thing class has access to the other namespace, then so does my php code outside of the Thing class. Unless I'm missing something about how namespaces work.

Comment: @barmar Yes, I referenced the Stripe code in my question. I've looked at it. It's complex and over my head. I'm asking if there's a simple(r) way to achieve this.

Comment: It doesn't prevent you from instantiating it, it just means you have to know the other namespace. That's why `new Products` gets an error, because it needs to be `new \StripeSomething\Products` (I just made up `StripeSomething` as an example).

Comment: @barmar Right, so that approach would not be a solution to my question then. I did say in the question that I don't want to know specifically how Stripe is doing this. I just want to know how it can be done. If Stripe is achieving it, then it would be nice to know how - that would answer my question. If Stripe isn't achieving it then it doesn't answer my question.

Comment: I'll say what I said before: I don't think you can do it. If the constructor can be called from a different class, it can be called from anywhere.

Comment: In order to get a new instance of something, then somewhere somehow you (or another library) need to call `new`.

Comment: @barmar - Right, so maybe there is a solution that doesn't involve a class named Products and therefore the issue with the constructor being public is overcome. I only included that example of my attempt in an effort to show what I'd tried to do. My attempt doesn't achieve my goal. I'm looking for something that does.

Comment: Other OOP do make this possible, but as yet PHP doesn't have the possibility to (for example) make a class completely private or protected within a namespace. I linked to something above which might come close, but even then it probably has flaws, and there's no code example.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think this is possible.

In order to create an instance of a class, either its constructor must be public, or it must have some other public method(s) that call the constructor. And if there's a public method that constructs it, that method can be called from anywhere.

You could make things difficult by having the constructor require an argument that can only come from private data of the class that's allowed to call it.

```
class ClassOne {
    private static $all_sentinels = [];
    private $sentinel;

    function __construct() {
        $this->sentinel = randomString();
        $this->all_sentinels[] = $this->sentinels;
    }

    function __get($name) {
        if ($name == 'classTwo') {
            return new ClassTwo($this, $this->sentinel);
        }
    }

    static function checkSentinel($s) {
        return in_array($s, $self::sentinels);
    }
}

class ClassTwo {
    function __construct($caller, $sentinel) {
        if (!ClassOne::checkSentinel($sentinel)) {
            throw new Exception("ClassTwo::__construct must be called from ClassOne");
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks. Given the way I was wording the question, I'm marking this as the correct answer because you're right - what I was specifically asking for can't be done. In my comments I was trying to explain that it would be nice to get a working example that uses some other approach - but it doesn't look like that's possible except for using something "difficult" as you suggested.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to anyone who posted those comments and gave this question some time.

I think you were all on the right track, and I had missed an obvious thing to check which would have shed a lot of light on this.

So...

In response to $prod = $stripe->products->retrieve(...) the Stripe code returns a Product object (not a Products object). And it turns out you CAN instantiate this with new \Stripe\Product.

So Stripe haven't prevented instantiating the object directly. I was just testing with the wrong class name.

Comment: I thought you said you didn't care how Stripe did it, you wanted to do this anyway.

Comment: Not exactly. If Stripe had achieved it, then it would be a potential answer. But if there was another answer, that would be ok too. It turns out that Stripe haven't achieved it - and that's what I'm clarifying here.